# Why doesn't an AsyncLocal flow from OWIN middleware to a WebForms page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, owin, katana

Find the full sample app demonstrating this problem [here](https://github.com/Aarskin/WebFormsWithOwinDemo).

I'm trying to use OWIN middleware to populate a static identifier that will be accessible by a WebForms page, but I'm noticing that with certain types this does not behave intuitively - specifically `AsyncLocal<T>`.

Consider the following *working* sample, using an `int`:

**Simple static container**

```
public static class Container
{
    public static int CallId { get; set; }
}
```

**Simple OWIN configuration**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            Container.CallId = 5;

            return next.Invoke();
        });
    }
}
```

**Simple Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Container.CallId != 5)
    {
        throw new Exception("What happened to CallId");
    }
}
```

This functions as expected. The middleware sets `CallId` to 5, the WebForms page sees a 5. The exception is not thrown.

---

Here's where things break intuition, if I want to use an `AsyncLocal<int>` for my CallId, *the value is no longer available in the WebForms page*. E.g.

**Broken Container**

```
public static class Container
{
    public static AsyncLocal<int> CallId { get; set; }
}
```

**Broken OWIN configuration**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            AsyncLocal<int> asyncId = new AsyncLocal<int>();
            asyncId.Value = 5
            Container.CallId = asyncId;

            return next.Invoke();
        });
    }
}
```

**Broken Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Container.CallId.Value != 5)
    {
        throw new Exception("What happened to CallId");
    }
}
```

This does *not* function as expected. An identifier is created in the middleware, but is not available in the page. *The exception is thrown*.

**Why?**

I'm struggling to piece together why this update breaks intuition; I can't think of anything that could be causing the value to disappear.

- The process, domain, and thread id all remain unchanged between the middleware component executing and the webform page's `On_Load`.
- `Container` is static, so only one instance exists in the domain.
- The difference in behavior doesn't hinge on primitive vs reference types; I tried this same thing with an simple `MyType`, `CallId` doesn't return to `null` in the WebForm

**Where did the static `CallId` value go?**

If you want to see this for yourself, here is a [demo github repo](https://github.com/Aarskin/WebFormsWithOwinDemo).

- Here's [the commit where things function intuitively](https://github.com/Aarskin/WebFormsWithOwinDemo/commit/660173b99e352b1163f6cfefdfc1bcb827c2b066).
- Here's [the commit where things function counter-intuitively](https://github.com/Aarskin/WebFormsWithOwinDemo/commit/bdca70508f17b59c533ed08d02582b4bf7974357).

Answer (score 2):

You are using it wrong. Use the local to hold the desired value.

```
public static class Container {
    private static AsyncLocal<int> current = new AsyncLocal<int>();

    public static int CallId { 
        get {
            return current.Value;
        } 
        set {
            current.Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And OWIN configuration remains as it did before.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.Use((context, next) => {
            Container.CallId = 5;
            return next.Invoke();
        });
    }
}
```

the `AsyncLocal<T>` class will now persist the value across asynchronous flows across threads.